# button with a radio button inside

Tags: android-studio, button, radio-button

I am currently usujng android studio and i have a radio button that i want the user to be able to click on the same line as the radio button stays, like a button with a radio button inside. Can someone guide me what can i add? Thank you.

i want a radio button inside of a button or something that can click and be able to choose the radio button

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of radio button as the area you want to be clickable.

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"/>
```